# For which values of $p$ and $q$ does the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(\ln n)^q}{\ n^p}$converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For which values of $p$ and $q$ does the serie $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(\ln(n))^q}{\ n^p}$converge? and For which values diverge.

I'm trying to use Cauchy Condensation Test but I can't show that the sequence is decreasing.

I am show that if $p-q<0$ then the series diverge (The zero test) and

if $p-q>1$ then the series converge (the comparison test)

Comment: Hint: $[\ln(p)]^q$ can be pulled out of the sum.

Comment: Presumably it should be $\ln(n)$.

Comment: Thanks, I dont think that.

Comment: (assuming carmichael561 is right)
if you can read a bit of french, this is called "bertrand series" in french undergrad studies: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand
(if he is not)
$p>1$

Comment: Obviously $(\ln p)^q$ is wrong, as that is constant. Please correct.

Comment: Correct it in the title too please.

Comment: Where you write "I am show" do you mean "I am trying to show"?

Answer (score 0):

Use the improper integral test.

If you are not allowed to use integrals you can use the following inequality and its inverse:

$$
log(n) < \frac{n}{k}
$$

where $k$ is any positive number ($n$ large enough) and apply the comparison test.